# При наведении на кнопку подсвечивается заголовок и сама кнопка.Как сделать?

Tags: html, css, hover

Нужно,чтобы при наведении только лишь на кнопку подсвечивался заголовок и сама кнопка.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Прочитайте пожалуйста правила форума. Тут никто не делает за вас работу, а только помогают в решении проблем, с которыми вы сами не справитесь. Выложите код, который вы набросали, а мы поможем.

Comment: @phen0men, не согласен.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Comment: Нормальный вопрос, не согласен. Ну добавит он какой-то код, например, как он поможет в поиске?

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114657/how-to-style-the-parent-element-when-hovering-a-child-element

Answer (score -1):

Как известно, влияние CSS распространяется вниз по иерархии, но не вверх. Так-что без трюков или JS это сделать нельзя.

**Трюк с CSS:**

Как это работает: Наведение на `.container` применяет цвет, однако наведение на `.wrapper` сразу же отменяет его. Поэтому, единственный способ навести на`.container` не наводя на `.wrapper`  - навести на кнопку

```css
div.container {
  position: relative
}

div.container:hover .wrapper .title {
  background: blue
}

div.container .wrapper:hover .title {
  background: white
}

div.container .wrapper{
  padding-bottom: 26px
}

div.container button {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0
}
```

```html
<div class=container>
 <div class=wrapper>
  <div class=title>
    Заголовок
  </div>
 <p>
    текст
    </p>
  </div>
  <button>кнопка</button>

</div>
```